# Can't push user-input to array in VueJS3

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi and sorry for the Newbie-Question
I am trying to push a HTML-Input into an existing array on Button-click, but i cannot find my mistake.
Can anyone spot the mistake? The console.log(user) stays undefined and I don't know why the let newUser() I create does not get pushed into the array.

```
    <template>
     <div> 
      <form @submit.prevent="customSubmit">
       <label>Name</label>
       <input type="text" required name="name" id="name">
       <label>E-mail:</label>
       <input type="email" required name="email" id="email">
       <label>Mobile Number</label>
       <input type="number" required name="number" id="number">
      </form>

      <button type="submit" class=buttonSignup @click="customSubmit">Submit</button>

     </div>
    </template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return{
     
        user:[{
            name: '',
            email:'',
            number:''
        }]
    };
},
methods: {
 
    
    customSubmit(){
        
        let newUser = {
            name: document.getElementById('name').value,
            email: document.getElementById('email').value,
            number: document.getElementById('number').value
        }
        this.user.push(newUser)
        console.log(this.user.value)
         
    },

    
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `this.user.value`  in your object, there is `this.user[0].name`, `this.user[0].email` and `this.user[0].number` ... Console log `this.user` first to see of you even push anything. Also this.user is array of objects, so you need target one of them to get name, email an number. or if you target this.user you should get all objects inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vue, you use v-model instead of directly accessing the DOM. For example, you can re-write your code by:

- Change name=name to v-model=user.name
- Use `user` and `users`.  `user` collects one user's data and `users` collects all user input into an array.  This is reflected in the modified customSubmit.
- Reset `user` after each input.
- There are more elegant ways to do this but this is the clearest and close enough to your original code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="customSubmit">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" required v-model="user.name" id="name">
      <label>E-mail:</label>
      <input type="email" required v-model="user.email" id="email">
      <label>Mobile Number</label>
      <input type="number" required v-model="user.number" id="number">
    </form>

    <button type="submit" class=buttonSignup @click="customSubmit">Submit</button>
    <br/>
    You typed:<br/>
    name: {{user.name}}<br/>
    email: {{user.email}}<br/>
    number: {{user.number}}

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],

      user: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        number: ''
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {


    customSubmit() {
      // do some checking here
      this.users.push(this.user)
      this.user = {name:'', email:'', number:''};
      console.log(this.users)

    },


  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Thats even better, than the previous solution suggested. 
And it feels a lot more natural for vue.